# Is it possible to translate CMS Images content type?

Tags: salesforce, content-management-system, salesforce-communities

I know how to translate documents CMS content using the standard translation feature on CMS. But how it works with the images?

I have custom content type and its content contains text and image field inside and I would like to have different images based on the users language. Actually I'm working with english and italy languages.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYA8v.png)

In this case is not possible to change the image of the translated content, only download.

Can someone give mesome advice on this?

I expect to be able to display different images based on the selected language in the public portal.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the how the CMS DB is structured, you'll need to enable dynamic content through a scripting language that looks at the user's language variable and then displays the proper images.